# How do you join all items in a list?

Tags: python, list, join

I have a list and it adds each letter of a word one by one to this list, I don't know what will be in the list until the program is run. How do I join each letter in the list into one word? e.g. turn `['p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n']` into `['python']`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
res = "".join(a)
```

You can again convert back to list of letters using :

```
list(res)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
''.join(str(v) for v in my_list)
```

Since you do not know what will be in the list

Answer (score 4):

`''.join(['p','y','t','h','o','n'])`

For more information see [str.join](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Comment: but i dont know what will be in the list, that was just an example

Comment: doesn't matter, if you have any list called `my_list` just call `"".join(my_list)`

Answer (score -3):

```
  s=""
  for v in [['p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n']:
         s+=v
  res=[s]
```

Comment: s = "-" and then  s.join(list)

Comment: a bracket is misplaced