# Checking for symbols and upper/lower-case for encrypting with ceasar cipher?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, caesar-cipher

I tried for several hours to make a simple ceasar cipher encryption programm. It finally works. But it is only able to encrypt text without spaces and symbols. I have no idea how to implement a checking part for these things into the code. Critics for making the code cleaner and DRY are appreciated. Thx.

**The Code where i tried to implement the functionality:**

```
#Taking Input String + converting to list
message = input("Enter the message for encrypting: ")
message_list = list(message)

#Taking Input Cipher
cipher = int(input("Enter shifting value (1-26): "))

#Alphabet
alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

#Defining variable
encrypted_message = []

#Shifting
for letter in message_list:
    if letter not in alphabet:
        encrypted_message.append(letter)
    else:
        #Getting Index of the letter in alphabet
        letter_position = alphabet.index(letter)
        #Getting the shifting value for the letter
        shifting_value = letter_position + cipher
        #Getting the shifted letter
        shifted_letter = alphabet[shifting_value]
        #Adding the corresponding letter to the encrypted message
        encrypted_message.append(shifted_letter)

#Output
print("Original Message: " + message)
print("Encrypted Message: " + str(encrypted_message))
print("Cipher: " + str(cipher))
```

**What it should do:**
 Encrypt the Message with spaces and symbols(ceasar cipher),

**What it is doing:**
 Exception has occurred: IndexError
list index out of range

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`).

Comment: You forget the modulus. `shifting_value = (letter_position + cipher) % 26`

Comment: modulus @kelalaka?

Comment: and that solves all problems? @kelalaka

Comment: Yes but in python 3.6

Comment: That solves the IndexError no other problems  were listed.

Comment: Now the output is a list

Comment: because you put into a list.

Comment: [How do you join all items in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174468/how-do-you-join-all-items-in-a-list)

Comment: You can also save yourself some code and performance by not keeping track of an alphabet list and instead checking whether the ord() of the character is within a range. [97-122]. You can then further use this instead of getting the index of the array for converting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IndexError list index out of range` error occurs since you forgot the modulus. Without the modulus,

```
shifting_value = letter_position + cipher
```

this line will have higher values then the array you are indexing. Remember, Ceasar cipher is

```
c = p + 3 mod 26
```

so the line must be

shifting_value = (letter_position + cipher) % 26

- Note 1 : cipher is not a good variable name here. It should be shiftAmount.
- Note 2: If you want to combine the list into string, use

  `str1 = ''.join(encrypted_message)`

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a arguably cleaner method taking into account the comments given.**

```
#Taking Input String + converting to list
message = input("Enter the message for encrypting: ")
message_list = list(message)

#Taking Input Cipher
cipher = int(input("Enter shifting value (1-26): "))

#Defining variable
encrypted_message = ''

#Shifting
for letter in message_list:
    code_point = ord(letter)
    if code_point > ord('z') or code_point < ord('a') :
        encrypted_message += letter
    else:
        #Getting Index of the letter in alphabet
        letter_position = code_point - ord('a')
        #Getting the shifting value for the letter
        shifting_value = (letter_position + cipher) % 26
        #Getting the shifted letter
        shifted_letter = chr(ord('a') + shifting_value)
        #Adding the corresponding letter to the encrypted message
        encrypted_message += shifted_letter

#Output
print("Original Message: " + message)
print("Encrypted Message: " + str(encrypted_message))
print("Cipher: " + str(cipher))
```

Of course can replace ord('a') and ord('z') with their respective values so that it does not have to calculate it, but it is good for understanding.

**Python 2.7 replace input with raw_input**

**Working version of the original:**

```
#Taking Input String + converting to list
message = input("Enter the message for encrypting: ")
message_list = list(message)

#Taking Input Cipher
cipher = int(input("Enter shifting value (1-26): "))

#Alphabet
alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

#Defining variable
encrypted_message = ''

#Shifting
for letter in message_list:
    if letter not in alphabet:
        encrypted_message += letter
    else:
        #Getting Index of the letter in alphabet
        letter_position = alphabet.index(letter)
        #Getting the shifting value for the letter
        shifting_value = (letter_position + cipher) % 26
        #Getting the shifted letter
        shifted_letter = alphabet[shifting_value]
        #Adding the corresponding letter to the encrypted message
        encrypted_message += shifted_letter

#Output
print("Original Message: " + message)
print("Encrypted Message: " + str(encrypted_message))
print("Cipher: " + str(cipher))
```